# CamelRedeliveryCounter not increasing after 2, no matter what's the value of maximumRedeliveries, is it bug?

Tags: apache-camel

Though it seems like sort of bug, but would like to confirm if somebody came across this situation in Apache Camel version **2.18.1.redhat-000021**, No matter what's the value for maximumRedeliveries, route on failure is only being tried twice.

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("amq:queue:ENTDLQ").maximumRedeliveries(5).useOriginalMessage()
            .onRedelivery((Exchange e) ->{
                log.info("--------------- Re-delivered..." + e.getIn().getHeaders());
            })
            .redeliveryDelay(2000).retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN));
```

> **Logs below**

**On delivery attempt: 0** caught: org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://0.0.0.0:0/someservice with statusCode: 404

--------------- Re-delivered...{CamelJmsDeliveryMode=2, **CamelRedelivered**=true, **CamelRedeliveryCounter**=1, **CamelRedeliveryMaxCounter**=5, JMSCorrelationID=Camel-ID-Shoaibs-MacBook-Pro-local-56371-1518552634307-0-6}

**On delivery attempt: 1** caught: org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://0.0.0.0:0/someservice with statusCode: 404

--------------- Re-delivered...{CamelJmsDeliveryMode=2, **CamelRedelivered**=true, **CamelRedeliveryCounter**=2, **CamelRedeliveryMaxCounter**=5, JMSCorrelationID=Camel-ID-Shoaibs-MacBook-Pro-local-56371-1518552634307-0-6}

Comment: Depends more on how you configure JMS with cache levels / transactions etc. You can use Red Hat customer portal to get help with the Red Hat Fuse product

Comment: Have tried with non-redhat version 2.18.1 as well, but the behaviour is same. Even have tried on the non-jms route to confirm if it's related to cache level for JMS but seems it's default behaviour for camel 2.18 onward as I have code in production with camel 2.17.0 and redelivery policy is just working fine. Just wanted to confirm if could raise it as bug.

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen - Issue seems to be with HTTP component, may be you can confirm if for HTTP component there are some restrictions with Redelivery of messages, as there is character limitation i can't post the full code here but adding it as answer so you can advise if there is extra configuration required for Redelivery attempts for HTTP component.

Comment: Try look at the maxConnectionsPerHost option on the http component

Comment: @ClausIbsen - So what I identified is if this particular exception is thrown "org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException" from the Route, Message Redelivery Policy is ignored and it will only re-try twice.
One way to produce this error is to use port "0" with HTTP component as below in the route:

from("timer://dummy?fixedRate=true&period=20s")
.log("========= Route Started..")
.to("http://0.0.0.0:0/somepath")

Strange why this particular exception is not re-tried more than twice by the redelivery policy.