# OnException maximumRedeliveries ignored

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

In the following route, the maximumRedeliveries clausule from redeliveryPolicy is ignored when we get an exception. We get:

*Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-248 on ExchangeId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-24). On delivery attempt: 0*

*Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-248 on ExchangeId: ID-UW205584-58231-1527668174534-39-24). On delivery attempt: 1*

And then it remains in a infinity loop repeating the last retry. Any idea? Thank you very much community!

Our route looks like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route handleFault="true">
        <from uri="switchyard://ProcessTaskEx"/>
        <log message="ProcessTaskEx - message received: ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="WebServiceQueues" />
        <to uri="switchyard://RequestCapacity"/>
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
             <exception>webservicequeues.utilities.WebServiceQueueException</exception>

            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="6000" maximumRedeliveryDelay="90000" retriesExhaustedLogLevel="INFO" retryAttemptedLogLevel="INFO"/>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>

            <log message="Failed after Retry.Sending ProcessTask Request to Error Queue" loggingLevel="ERROR" logName="WebServiceQueues" />
            <to uri="switchyard://ErrorProcessTaskExQueue"/>
        </onException>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you get an infinite loop, it sounds like the message header `CamelRedeliveryCounter` gets overwritten every time and therefore it never reaches the `maximumRedeliveries` of 2.

Is it possible that the call to the endpoint where the error occurs deletes or resets message headers? Particularly `CamelRedeliveryCounter`?

Comment: I don't think so. We perform no action with the headers and I have set all the transformers to plane transformations, might it be a bug..? We have it after an upgrade from Fuse 6.1 camel 2.1 to Fuse 6.3 Camel 2.17 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774952/camelredeliverycounter-not-increasing-after-2-no-matter-whats-the-value-of-max

Comment: To find out if it is an endpoint problem I would replace the endpoint `RequestCapacity` with a simple bean that throws for example a `WebServiceQueueException` and probably replace the `ErrorProcessTaskExQueue` endpoint with a Camel mock. If the redelivery policy then works as expected, the `switchyard` endpoints seem to cause this issue.

Comment: Hi Burki, I tried what you said. Actually I just changed <to uri="switchyard://RequestCapacity"/> (which returns a SOAP Fault) with a bean that raises the WebServiceQueueException and now it works...So, does it mean that this issue happens if we get a SOAP fault? Rgs

Comment: In this last case I have:   On delivery attempt: 1 caught: webservicequeues.utilities.WebServiceQueueException: ProcessTaskEx Service not available, in the previous case I had: On delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelException:

Comment: I did not mock the error queue, so  will it be a problem in the exception handling I assume...

Comment: Either Camel redelivery has a problem with faults OR (as I assumed in my answer) the `switchyard://RequestCapacity` bothers somehow the Camel redelivery. To eliminate the first you would have to build a simple mock webservice that throws a fault and call it from your route instead of `switchyard://RequestCapacity`. If redelivery still works, the endpoint causes the problem. If redelivery no more works with the simple webservice, Faults in general seem to be a problem.

Comment: Hi Burki, I did it, I Mock locally a SOAP fault with another text, and it got stuck again in an infinity loop...

Comment: Then it looks like there is a general problem with Faults and redelivery. Have you tried using another Camel minor version or the most current release?

Comment: In such cases I normally build an as small as possible example project that shows the problem and is very easy to run (Camel route test). I then submit it to the [Camel user mailinglist](http://camel.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) to allow the developers to check if it is a bug or another problem.

Comment: Well, we are using Jboss Fuse 6.3 which comes with Camel 2.17, so we have to stick with this version...I will do it, I will recreate the problem, send to the camel mail list and to the jboss support. :) I let you know the outcome. If you have any other ideas... Let me know! I assume this will take some weeks... Rgs

Comment: Yes please. I am curious if this really is a bug/problem. Thanks

Comment: I am in contact with jboss support, meanwhile, after changing some properties internally, I see the following: 09:10:47,302 SEVERE [com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) SAAJ0303: Operation getFaultSubcodes not supported by SOAP 1.1 
09:10:47,302 INFO  [org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler] (Thread-4 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-32602662)) Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-UW205584 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelException: (functional error) . And it repeats again and again, could this be the error causing the infinity loop?

Comment: I have see as well if I remove the redelivery policy and I add the following error line to the route: <log message="ProcessTaskEx - message to error queue: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="be.eandis.WebServiceQueues" /> just before the errorqueue, I see that ${body} is empty...